# Load Partial View inside of Popover

Tags: html, asp.net, twitter-bootstrap, asp.net-core, razor

I have a popover which is supposed to display a partial view. I have attempted to load the partial view as one would outside of a popover and it doesn't work. I tested to see if my partial was the issue, but it renders fine outside of the popover. The popover code is as follows:

```html
<a tabindex="0" class="btn btn-danger position-relative" data-placement="top" role="button"
   data-html="true" data-toggle="popover" data-trigger="click" title="Report"
    data-content='<partial name="_FlagPartial"/>'> @*this line is the one that doesn't work as i expect*@
     Flag ⚐
</a>
```

How can I load my partial inside my popover?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the `data-content` like below:

```
data-content='@await Html.PartialAsync("~/Views/Shared/_FlagPartial.cshtml")'
```

Or:

```
data-content='@{await Html.RenderPartialAsync("_FlagPartial");}'
```

Comment: I tried both and oddly they both gave me the button but with the partial view inside of the button, not the popover: [image](https://imgur.com/a/fydM6zT)

Comment: I believe the issue might have been that the quotation marks matched. If you change it to ```data-content='@{await Html.RenderPartialAsync("_FlagPartial");}'``` it works great